# how can I get the email of the user from firestore in cloud functions?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

Here is the javascript for sending welcome email:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

const userID = firestore.auth().currentUser.getId();
exports.sendWelcomeEmail =
    functions.firestore.document('Users/{userID}').onCreate(async event => {
        const name = event.data.data().name;
        const email = event.data.data().email;



        return sendWelcomeEmail(email, name);
    })

function sendWelcomeEmail(email, name) {
    const mailOptions = {
        from: `${APP_NAME} <jagdish.choudhary@iitgn.ac.in>`,
        to: email,
    };


    mailOptions.subject = `Welcome to ${APP_NAME}!`;
    mailOptions.text = `Hey ${name || ''}! Welcome to ${APP_NAME}. I hope 
you will enjoy our service.`;
    return mailTransport.sendMail(mailOptions).then(() => {
        return console.log('New welcome email sent to:', email);
    });
}
```

I have firestore database like Users > userID > name,email.

Please help me with this.

Comment: At what point in your code, you need that? You are already reading email from firestore when the record is created right.

Comment: When I am creating an event I need  userID for the path give as 'Users/{userID}' . Otherwise what value will  it (userId) take?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @ArnavRao said, you should retrieve the data as you did. It seams correct and you don't need this line above : `const userID = firestore.auth().currentUser.getId();`  But if you need definitely the user Id:

```
...
const name = event.data.data().name;
const email = event.data.data().email;
const userId = event.params.userID;
...
```

will give you new record's id.